# Alfresco Rest Api

Tags: android, rest, alfresco

How do I use the Alfresco REST API to  search a document from a particular folder? 
I want to actually get the node value of a particular file from Alfresco.

Comment: what kind of information do you have for looking up the document? The title? Path? Textual content?

Comment: I have title of the file

Comment: Title or file name? Cause it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all folder childrens you can use the following query:

To get the data of object childrens by nodeRef

```
nodeRef = b544cd67-e839-4c60-a616-9605fa2affb7;   
url: "/../alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/" + nodeRef + "/children"
method: "GET"
```

nodeRef - folder id in Alfresco.
Returns data in xml format.

This resource is available for viewing the other queries with complete description.

http://jazzteam.org/en/technical-articles/list-of-alfresco-services/

Answer (score 0):

Did you find any useful information at Alfresco [wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Package%3a_.2Forg.2Falfresco.2Frepository.2Fsearch)?

You should be able to send a POST query to  /alfresco/service/api/query with the parameters:

- String statement: Query statement
- (Optional) Bool searchAllVersions: False (Default)
- (Optional) Boolean includeAllowableActions: False (default)
- (Optional) Enum includeRelationships: none (default), source, target, both
- (Optional) int maxItems: 0 = Repository-default number of items (Default)
- (Optional) int skipCount: 0 = Start at first position (Default)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below REST services to search
[Alfresco Content Services REST API Search](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/?urls.primaryName=Search%20API#/search/search)

Below can be used
POST http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/search/versions/1/search

Request Body

```
{
"query": {
    "query": "PATH:'/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:test/cm:documentLibrary/cm:folderName//*' ",
    "language": "afts"
   }
}
```